# Change HTML code to json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, json

I have some JSON and JavaScript code ready for creating tracks code for video player, in my case for JWPlayer. I want the same code but I need to use for other player like JS-Video.

first code :

```
$subtitleArr[] = json_encode(
  array('src'=>'some-url/subtitle.vtt',
        'label'=>'English',
        'kind'=>'captions')
);
```

second code :

```
tracks: [< ?php echo str_replace('\/', '/', implode(',', $subtitleArr)); ?>]
```

jw player code:

```
tracks: [{ 
  file: "some-url/subtitle.vtt", 
        label: "English",
        kind: "captions"
}]
```

and I want to get that :

```
< track kind="captions" src="some-url/subtitle.vtt" label="english">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `json_encode` an entire array so, change the first part to this:

```
$subtitleArr[] = 
  array('src'=>'some-url/subtitle.vtt',
        'label'=>'English',
        'kind'=>'captions');
```

The second part to this

```
// I assume tracks is a property of some object otherwise I'd switch this to `var tracks = ...`
tracks : <?php echo json_encode($subtitleArr); ?>;
```

And to create the element using JS

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById('presumablyYourVideoElement');

for(var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
    var track = document.createElement('track');
    track.kind = tracks[i].kind;
    track.label = tracks[i].label;
    track.src = tracks[i].src;
    parentElement.appendChild(track);
}
```

Comment: oh , sorry ,, I  means second code give jw player code ,, it is an example,  , second code give tracks: [{ 
  file: "some-url/subtitle.vtt", 
        label: "English",
        kind: "captions"
}]   but I want to get   < track kind="captions" src="some-url/subtitle.vtt" label="english">

Comment: @SulejmanVulaj Get `< track kind="captions" src="some-url/subtitle.vtt" label="english">` how? You want to echo out the html using PHP?

Comment: with javascript ,,, u can have a look at videojs , I want that by javascript not with html